# Hyperion interactive reporting and JDEdwards

Tags: hyperion

I am new using it, and have a question.

I need to join two files using a field that has different length.

In the file01. the field is text (3 characters) in the file02 the field is text (8 characters), both fieold has the data to the rigth side ( with spaces before)

So  i need make some someting like that: trim(file01.field)=trim(file02.field).

Can you help me?. I don't know how to make advanced joins in Oracle Hyperion Interactive..

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

you are working with local results and you have less options.
Try:
- import file01, after importing add a new computed item to join with Rtrim function;
- do the same to the file02
- insert a new query, go to local results and add the files (tables) to console and join this two tables by the new key.

Hugo